# Why does CodeBlocks 12.11, on windows, underline my comments with red zigzag lines, and how do I turn this feature off?

Tags: c++, windows-7, codeblocks

How do I turn off the "spell-checker like" feature in CodeBlocks on windows?

I also just now realized that if I add a "\" (back-slash) to the end of my comment, the next line if code is also commented. Has this always been standard for c++?

[image]

Comment: Yes, the backslash at the end of the line continues it on the next line. You should be able to go `Plugins->Manage Plugins...->SpellChecker->Disable` for the red lines.

Comment: that spell checker can be pretty useful, actually. Any specific reason *why* you'd like to turn it off, just out of curiosity?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, It's caught a few mistakes I've had, but I have to give the OP that it is pretty annoying sometimes.

Comment: @RiaD, I'm not sure what's up with that. Mine doesn't highlight any for the exact same code, though I have seen it become pretty bad.

Comment: I suppose it might be beneficial since I am still learning, but I was hoping that I could turn it off for comments only. It is making longer comments harder to read.

Comment: @chris well, that might be the case with C::B. Visual Studio's one has significantly improved lately, and I agree that the old one was a bit... off.

Comment: @chris Thanks chris, you have solved the issue!

Comment: You don't need to turn off the plugin...Chelsea's answer would do fine

Comment: @H2CO3 Although helpful as per my up-vote it did not include how to disable comment spell checking whereas Rashedul's answer addressed this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Open Code::Blocks.
2. Go to plugins -> Manage Plugins
3. Select Spell Checker and disable it.

Answer (score 16):

Mine was underlining all my comments and strings, too. Turns out when I downloaded codeblocks, the language wasn't set to English. If you look in the bottom right corner of the codeblocks window, there is a little flag. You can right click it and select the correct language. Hope this helps!

Comment: And to add words to the dictionary, you can right-click on the word and select "Spelling suggestions for '<word>'" followed by "Add '<word>' to dictionary". (Also, +1 because, while not specifically addressing either of the OP's questions, this is possibly the most useful answer.)

Comment: It seems to me that this should be the accepted solution since disabling a feature is just working around it, rather than solving it.

Answer (score 1):

> Has this always been standard for c++?

Well, rather for the C preprocessor (which C++ uses exhaustively). Yes, it's a documented feature: the backslash-newline sequence acts as a line continuation marker (i. e., the backslash "invalidates", escapes the newline, effectively making the preprocessor treat the consecutive lines separated by backslashes as one line).

Comment: I'd also add that it even makes sense! (which is funny, since it's C) Since all special chars are preceeded by `\ `, `\ ` before newline seems natural.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, quite. I don't agree with the sarcastic part, though :P C is one of the most logical languages, IMO.

Comment: True, it does make sense given that you understand the preprocessor treats each character including newline as a single element of a character array. Whereas entering `\\n` in a string literal would evaluate to two characters `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

The falsely underlined words, might be caused by not having a dictionary selected. This is how I fixed it.

Click Settings->Editor->Spell Checker(on left of dialog) then under Language select a dictionary in the drop down.